# Combining Heroku with custom external services (e. g. Varnish or Postgres on EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, varnish, cache, latency, heroku

I'm planning to set up a Django site on Heroku. It will run on Heroku's Cedar stack, which allows Python apps, but doesn't include or support HTTP upstream caching with Varnish like the other stacks do.

It will be a very read-heavy site and I'd like to use Varnish for HTTP caching. I guess it should be possible to set up my own Varnish instance, point the site's A record to that instance and then have it fetch and cache the content from my Heroku app.

I thought that for minimizing latency, it would be a good idea to host that instance on EC2 in the same availability zone Heroku is in.

Do you think the overall idea is feasible? Do you have any experience how to choose the right geographical location for that EC2 instance so that its requests to the Heroku app will be as fast as possible?

Thanks!

Edit: same question goes for setting up a custom PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: I'm looking at the same situation and I'd be curious to hear if you have an update. I haven't had the time to test it yet, but running Varnish on an EC2 instance doesn't seem like *that* bad an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a bad track trying to do that; Heroku could, at any time, move their stuff around to somewhere far, far away from your instance.  You'd be far better off talking to Heroku to get your concerns addressed within their platform.